# How do I create a standalone Jupyter Lab server using Pyinstaller or similar?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pyinstaller, jupyter-lab

I would like to create a self-contained, .exe file that launches a JupyterLab server as an IDE on a physical server which doesn't have Python installed itself.

The idea is to deploy it as part of an ETL workflow tool, so that it can be used to view notebooks that will contain the ETL steps in a relatively easily digestible format (the notebooks will be used as pipelines via papermill and scrapbook - not really relevant here).

While I can use Pyinstaller to bundle JupyterLab as a package, there isn't a way to launch it on the Pythonless server (that I can see), and I can't figure out a way to do it using Python code alone.

Is it possible to package JupyterLab this way so that I can run the .exe on the server and then connect to 127.0.0.1:8888 on the server to view a notebook?

I have tried using the link below as a starting point, but I think I'm missing something as no server seems to start using this code alone, and I'm not sure how I would execute this via a tornado server etc.:
https://gist.github.com/bollwyvl/bd56b58ba0a078534272043327c52bd1

I would really appreciate any ideas, help, or somebody to tell my why this idea is impossible madness!

Thanks!

Phil.

P.S. I should add that Docker isn't an option here :( I've done this before using Docker and it's extremely easy.

Comment: Pythonless server, yet running Python application? Do you mean a server without a Python >>kernel<<? I cannot quite understand what you try to achieve. The link you provided is very old (uses `NotebookApp` instead of `ServerApp`/`JupyterLabApp` etc).

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. I want a standalone application that runs a JupyterLabs server. I can, for example, package a Flask application using Pyinstaller and have that run a Flask server on a machine without a Python environment installed, and I'd like to do the same thing with Jupyter. I know the link is very old, the scarcity of useful results from my googling is why I've resorted to asking the question myself :)

Comment: And you don't want a simple ipynb → html conversion (like [`nbconvert`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))? Do you depend on any JupyterLab extensions so that you want to keep the interface but in read-only mode? Do you want widgets in the notebooks to be interactive? Have you considered [voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila)?

Comment: No, the notebooks wouldn't be outputs, the idea is that the application will use papermill to run the notebooks as ETL pipelines. The JupyterLabs server would then be used to open them up and make any changes if anything breaks - like a mini IDE. I'm doing it this way rather than scripting all the ETL in Python as I need as I want the visual aspect of the notebook to have a fighting chance of somebody other than me being able to follow the transformations :)